# How to import root CA certificate into JxBrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

Is it possible to import a root CA cert into JxBrowser, or otherwise disable Chromium's certificate checks?

We want to use JxBrowser in OWASP ZAP which is a security tool that allows you to intercept HTTPS traffic by re-signing it with its own root CA certificate. 
By default JxBrowser ignores certificate errors and with v6.11 it all worked fine. With 6.12 we are no longer able to access google.com when proxying through ZAP, which I'm guessing could that be due to certificate pinning.
We want to be able to use JxBrowser 'out of the box' so that our users dont have to manually import the ZAP root CA into their machines certificate store.
Any suggestions for ways we can make this work gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

[JxBrowser](https://teamdev.com/jxbrowser) doesn't provide such functionality. It allows filtering SSL certificates, decide whether invalid certificate can be ignored or not, allows accessing certificate information, etc., but it doesn't allow setting your own root CA certificate and use it for HTTPS.

We do have similar feature request in our backlog. Please [submit feature request](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/tickets/new) via your account in JxBrowser Help Center, so we could associate your request with appropriate task in our issue tracking system. Being able to associate your request with the feature request, we can notify when this functionality is implemented and available for download.

**UPD:** The feature has been implemented in JxBrowser 6.14. The following example demonstrates how to use the new API:

```
browser.setDialogHandler(new DefaultDialogHandler(view) {
    @Override
    public CloseStatus onSelectCertificate(CertificatesDialogParams params) {
        X509Certificate x509Certificate = loadCertificate();
        params.setSelectedCertificate(new Certificate(x509Certificate));
        return CloseStatus.OK;
    }
});
```